# solr : how to boost query term after tokenizer

Tags: solr, tokenize, solr-boost

If the query word is "ABCD", then after being tokenized it is "A" "BC" "D". I want to boost term "BC", so the query word is like this:

```
A BC^10 D" and phrase query "ABCD"
```

All query words users typing in will be processed like that automaticly so that important query terms will be boosted.

I guess I can custom a new Tokenizer to do it, but I don't know if it is feasible, or is there some other methods simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [QueryElevationComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent). If you put words like BC in your elevate.xml file, then those terms will be automatically boosted at query time. If you have added the componant to your request handler of course.

EDIT:

I think you meant boosting terms rather than documents for a term.
I think in your case, it might work if you look for the specific term using regexes and whitelists and alter the string to include the boosts before you send to solr.

```
    [Fact]
    public void Boost()
    {
        var query = "ABCD";
        var importantTerms = new List<string>{ "BC"};
        importantTerms.ForEach(term => query = query.Replace(term, string.Format("+{0}^10+", term)));
        Assert.Equal("A+BC^10+D", query);
    }
```

Comment: using QueryElevationComponent ，if query words match those word in elevate.xml file,specific docid will be returned.but l just want to boost that term. looking for the specific term using regexes will be fine,so l need to custom a  Tokenizer or filter to alter the string to boosts the specific terms?

Comment: No, The boosting needs to be specified before solr tokenizes the query. You need to convert ABCD into `A+BC^10.0+D` in your client code. Ill edit the answer to show an example in C#